Contact Tag duplication while sending the message to ContactManager
I have encountered a failed message in the ContactMessageTransport queue of PolicyCenter with the following error: "Cannot add to tags with a non-null Link ID".
I have observed that in the payload, there is an attribute "action" with the value as "add" which asks ContactManager to add the specific tag to the contact. But with the same tag, there is also an associated LinkID which means that the tag is already added, and this is a duplication.
I want to understand how a tag is added to the message payload. I have all the places where "addToTags()" method is called but couldn't find the root cause of it.
I'm expecting to find the root cause of the issue and to understand how a tag is being added to the contact's payload.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
